# partition over product and sector

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Here a description of the tables and what I try to do:

```sql
WITH Time AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,48),(201,520),(36,120))V(id_project,time)),
SectorProject AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,'BM'),(1011,'Fi'),(1011,'Om'),(201,'BM'),(36,'BM'))V(id_project,Sector1)),
    prductProject AS(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES(1011,'bike'),(1011,'velo'),(1011,'pc'),(201,'n'),(36, 'r' ))V(id_project,product))
select
 T.id_project, Sector1 ,product, sum(time) as time
,  avg( sum(time))  over(partition by Sector1,product)
as avgtilme
from time T left join
     SectorProject SP 
     on SP.id_Project = T.id_Project 
     left join
     prductProject P 
     on p.id_Project = T.id_Project 
     group by T.id_project, Sector1,product
     order by T.id_project,product
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=97af35b3cf85e6592fc56b4b368fe00d)

Here the expected result:

[image]

How could I partition 48 over sector and product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the average divided by the count *per project*.  One method is:

```
avg( sum(time)) over (partition by t.id_project) * 1.0 / count(*) over (partition by t.id_project)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your request and data structure correctly, you should be able to calculate that by using the following within your SELECT `clause`

```
(0.0+t.time)/(count(1) over(partition by t.id_project))
```

The `0.0+` is only present to get around automatic casting to integer.